# FF Addon SDK page mod script to content script communication not working

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk, postmessage

For starters, I've been trying to allow communication from a page script to a content script. If the docs are accurate, this should be easy. Here's what I'm doing, I believe fully in accordance with https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/communicating-with-other-scripts.html#Using%20the%20DOM%20postMessage%20API :

And here's my live **[test case](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/201155/latest/)**:

main.js:

```
exports.main = function() {
    var data = require('sdk/self').data,
            pageMod = require('sdk/page-mod');

    pageMod.PageMod({
        include: '*',
        contentScriptFile: data.url('postMessageRelay.js'),
    });
};
```

postMessageRelay.js

```
// Trying with window.addEventListener also doesn't work
document.defaultView.addEventListener('message', function (e) { // e.data, e.origin

    console.log('would be good if it got here:'+e.data);

});
console.log('it gets here at least');
```

And the JavaScript within a [regular HTML file](http://brett-zamir.me/tests/webappfind-test2.html) (on a normal remote server, not file or localhost):

```
try {
    window.postMessage('webappfind', window.location.href);
}
catch(e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

This really looks like either a full-blown bug for this functionality or a problem with the docs... I had similar problems trying to communicate via [custom events](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/communicating-with-other-scripts.html#Using%20Custom%20DOM%20Events) so going a little bananas...

Comment: Your addon code is fine. But your test web page uses window.location.domain (== undefined) as the target origin.

Comment: Sorry, had been asked to try that value and forgot that I was linking from it here. I've reverted it back to "window.location.href". But it also doesn't work with `*` at http://brett-zamir.me/tests/webappfind2.html though it does work when [used from window.open](http://brett-zamir.me/tests/webappfind3.html) and sometimes when [used from an iframe to parent](http://brett-zamir.me/tests/webappfind-iframeHolder.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in [Bug 910972](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=910972), but leaving it here to for future visitors of SO:

The issue was with the page immediately firing `postMessage` in the head tag, so the page-mod script isn't even yet attached to the page to listen to the message event. The communication back and forth between page and content scripts [as in this example works](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/communicating-with-other-scripts.html#Using%20the%20DOM%20postMessage%20API) as long as this timing is taken into consideration

Comment: And I solved this by adding `contentScriptWhen: 'start'` to the `PageMod()` constructor call... (and thanks again!)